# can't make Wand work on mac OS

Tags: python, imagemagick, macos-high-sierra, wand

I tried (again) to install [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/guide/install.html) on my mac and it does not work.

I'm running High Sierra, I installed it with

```
easy_install Wand
```

after brewing ImageMagick

```
brew install imagemagick
```

and I run the "magic" command

```
export MAGICK_HOME=/opt/local
```

to fix the path issue, but it didn't work.
The installation is successfull but when I Import wand I get:

```
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-mac
```

Can anyone explain me how to fix the path?

Comment: Is wand compatible with ImageMagick 7, which I assume you installed? Have you tried installing ImageMagick 6 rather than ImageMagick 7?

Comment: Use `brew install imagemagick@6` to install ImageMagick-6, and don't bother setting `MAGICK_HOME` unless the dylib's are installed under `/opt/local`. With macOS SIP, it might be better to install wand through `pip install Wand` via virtualenv.

Comment: @fmw42 do I have to uninstall ImageMagick7 to install the 6? or it's gonna just overwrite it? I'm gonna try it right now (thanks!)

Comment: @emcconville see above

Comment: I just installed imagemacick 6 and even run this command
    If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

to have it first in my PATH, but I still get the same error message saying that imagemagick is probably not installed :/